# Why does the Go Jetters theme tune mix up the calls and responses?

Tags: go-jetters

The [Go Jetters](https://mobile.twitter.com/gojetters/status/701721959156084737?lang=en) theme tune, contains two sequences where the call and response are mixed up.[image: Go Betters Theme]

Is there a reason why the song isn't the more logical

'Four heroes always learning; Guided by Ubercorn'

'Outside the World is turning; There's just so much to explore'

Comment: Probably because Ubercorn is part of the team, so it would make sense to include him right after introducing the other members of the team.

Comment: @JohnnyBones that's fine, but you can still introduce Ubercorn by describing what he does (Help the Heroes learn) rather than by making it sound like he guides the turning of the globe. On the other hand, he is a unicorn...